# Google Maps Street View v3: prevent the navigation links?

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

Let's say I have a street view added to my webpage.  I only want the user to navigate down the street, and to not turn the corner to another street.  Is there a way to limit what street links are shown, or else catch a request and ignore it if it is not for that street?

Comment: How have you "added" street view to your webpage?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), set [{linksControl: false} in the panoramaOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanoramaOptions), then create your own controls that only allow the behavior you want.